# sonar code coverage is not displaying

Tags: sonarqube

Which plug-in needs to installed to get the code coverage metrics in sonar reports? It was working fine for previous version(3.7.3) and now I am using 4.1.1 I can only see the unit test coverage. I need both if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can only see the unit test coverage"? What's missing then?

Comment: Hi David, Code coverage is missing.

Comment: If we're talking about Java, the code coverage tool provided by default is JaCoCo. If you set the code coverage tool to Cobertura, Emma or Clover, you need to download the related plugin. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project